# Why JUnit 4.11 is not working in Ant build file, but JUnit 4.8.2 is working fine?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, junit

I am using IntelliJ for the Java Projects. As I am new to Java, I tried Ant as a build tool in my project.

When I am using Junit 4.11 in my Ant build file, I am getting the following errors:

```
[javac] /Users/rajatg/fizz-buzz/src/test/FizzBuzzTest.java:4: error: package org.hamcrest.core does not exist
[javac] import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
[javac]                                ^
[javac] /Users/rajatg/fizz-buzz/src/test/FizzBuzzTest.java:4: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
[javac] import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
[javac] ^
[javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
```

And when I used Junit 4.8.2, then all the tests ran successfully.

Can anyone tell me please, what is this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole project is present on GitHub. The project URL is https://github.com/rajatguptarg/fizz-buzz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Junit 4.11 has the compile time dependency of org.hamcrest.core. You should add the org.hamcrest.core to your classpath.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.11

Junit 4.8.2 doesn't have the compile time dependency. As you can see from the following link, the org.hamcrest.core package is already in the junit jar.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.8.2